# The inequality $|x-f(x)| \leq 1/2 |x| $ implies $ |x-x'| \leq 2|f(x)-f(x')|$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am reading a proof of inverse function theorem where the following inequality is used:

It's been established that $$|F(x)-F(x')| \leq 1/2 |x-x'|$$ for every $x,x' \in B_{\delta}(0)$ for some $\delta >0$ where $F(x)=x-f(x)$ for smooth $f$, with invertible derivative at the origin. And in particular if we let $x'=0$ we get
$$|F(x)| \leq 1/2 |x|$$
Then from the above the author claims that $|x-x'| \leq 2 |f(x)-f(x')|$. Somehow I fail to see how we get that. Must be a simple triangle inequality or something. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f(x)-f(x')|=|(x'-x)-(F(x')-F(x)|\geq |x'-x| -|(F(x)-f(x')|\geq |x'-x| - \frac 1 2 |x'-x| =\frac  1 2 |x'-x| $.

Comment: Thank you so much!